# Memory leaks in nodejs websocket server

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, websocket

I'm using websockets to transfer video files, this means they are large files.
The server side (and also the client side) is implemented using nodejs, with binaryjs in javascript.

It worked fine, until I started having a great number of clients, what made the server crash (process was killed by Linux OS). As I observed, it ran out of memory, since for every client it's taking a lot of it, but the thing is that when the client disconnects this memory is not freed. I think this should be done internally and that I should not worry about memory, am I wrong? may I be doing something wrong?

As I've seen, that "send" function is reserving memory to save what it has to send but never frees it. (If you comment that line, there's no memory problem)
Here's the code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var BinaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
var bs = BinaryServer({port: 8080});

var nchunks=116;

bs.on('connection', function(client){
for(var i=1; i<=nchunks; i++)
{
    var name="/var/www/1.m4s";
    var fd=fs.openSync(name.replace("1.m4s", i+".m4s"), 'r');
    var buf = new Buffer(fs.fstatSync(fd).size, 'binary');
    fs.readSync(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, null)
    client.send(buf);
    fs.closeSync(fd);

    if(i==nchunks){
        client.send("end"); 
    }
}
client.on('close', function(c){
    console.log("closing");
});
```

});

When the clients receives all of the video files, closes the socket, so I know it's getting closed since I'm capturing "close" event on server. Shouldn't it at this moment free the memory?

The worst thing is, as I couldn't find the error, I thought it might be due to how binaryjs implements it so I tried also with "ws" and "websocket-node" with same results in the memory.

Has anyone experienced this problems? Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't it at this moment free the memory

No, JavaScript is a garbage collected language and the garbage collector runs periodically as the runtime deems suitable. You have no control nor awareness of when or if it will run and thus free memory.

Also, you cannot use any synchronous IO calls in a network server as all of your client processing will block while you do each of those IO calls.

I think your primary problem is you are not streaming the files down in reasonably-small chunks. You are trying to read entire files into memory and send them down.

```
var buf = new Buffer(fs.fstatSync(fd).size, 'binary');
```

Don't do that. Use a ReadableStream and send files down in a series of small chunks, and use asynchronous calls. This is how to get node to work correctly for you. Lack of streaming and lack of asynchronous calls are sure paths to failure in node. Here's a working example program.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen(9200)
server.on('request', function (req, res) {
  fs.createReadStream('/tmp/test1').pipe(res);
});
```

I tested this on OSX with node v0.10.7 and I can repeatedly request the file with `curl localhost:9200 >/dev/null` and watching `lsof -p <pid of node>` I can see the `/tmp/test` file get opened and closed properly.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks a lot for the information, I didn't know much about the garbage collector. 

Yes, I read the complete file but the size of each file is about 60kb, since I chunked a not very long video 
into small pieces, so all I send are tiny chunks. 
Do you have any proposal of how big should this chunks be to work efficiently?

Comment: About the ReadableStream, I've tried to use it for weeks, but I experienced a big problem and it is that although 
the documentation says it closes every file it opens at the end, it let all my files opened. And I didn't find a way
to close them myself, cause it wouldn't give the file descriptor. This problem was even bigger, since the server crashed
completely, as in Linux everything works with files. (Many files x many clients)
If you've worked with streaming in node, did you look at that?

Comment: Of course I was using fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res); and I can assure you it was not closing the files, as I have said. I've read the complete documentation and that's not how it should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: You're right, that example is closing all the files! I was doing it wrong, thanks! Nevertheless I just saw with the readablestream it still runs out of memory :(

Comment: When you say ' garbage collected language ', what does this mean in layman terms? Javascript will periodically clean the memory every xxx seconds? See [my issue here with nodejs and webscoekts](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/509) is this a memory leak or intended?

Comment: @NiCkNewman https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: Hmmm, must be a memory leak in the ws module for node then. Because all I am doing is `WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server, wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 9300}); ` and each time somoene connects, the memory usage increases incrementally upon EACH new connection and doesn't go down (Release the allocated memory). Bummer. I might switch out to a different module then thanks @PeterLyons

Comment: @NiCkNewman it is highly unlikely there is a memory leak in `ws`. Understanding memory usage and what constitutes a leak is probably more complex/involved than you are ready for. It's not always intuitive and you need to understand the tools and use them correctly.

Comment: @PeterLyons As I said before, all I have inside my .js file is: `WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server, wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 9300});` and whenever someone opens a connection to this port on the client (the browser), the memory usage is incremental and increases per refresh.  I don't know what else could be causing the leak? That is literally all the code in the file, not even a console log is there lol.